# when i add a Multires modifier to my model some of edge are broke what should

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, edges

when i add a  Multires modifier to my model some of edge are broke what should

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file? You can use blend-exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this topology instead (here on a 32 vertex cylinder) and you should avoid bad pinching:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help